# 80's movie where a prisoner is a electrocuted but his spirit continues to kill people?

Tags: story-identification, movie

While watching a commercial for "Transcendence" it reminded me of a late 80's movie I saw.

It is about a prisoner put to death in the electric chair, and after he was executed his spirit could travel through the wires and kill people.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Would that be Wes Craven's '[Shocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocker_(film))' (1989)?

Relevant info from Wikipedia:

> Pinker is quickly convicted and sentenced to die in the electric chair. [...] But what they do not realize is that Pinker has made a "deal with the devil". When he is executed, he does not actually die but instead becomes pure electricity, and is able to possess others (it is unknown if the possessed hosts live or die after Pinker leaves their body since some of them were shown to be lying motionless after being released) to continue his murderous ways.

Comment: I was going to say *Ghost in the Machine*, until that bit an execution. I'm pretty sure you've got the right answer here.

Comment: *Shocker* was the movie that immediately came to my mind, too.

Answer (score 2):

Could be the movie just simply called *[Prison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prison_(1987_film))* from 1987? A guy is electrocuted and years later he comes back to haunt the new warden killing everyone in sight.

[image: Prison movie poster]

> In 1964, inmate Charlie Forsythe swallowed 60,000 volts of electricity for a murder he did not commit.
>
> When Creedmore Prison is reopened after thirty years, it has not been standing empty. Charlie Forsythe is back – still charged with electric heat. Waiting for Eaton Sharpe (Lane Smith) – the man who stood by as Forsythe rode the electric chair.
>
> Forsythe quickly makes up for lost time as his vengeance rises to a fever pitch of violent fury. Burke (Viggo Mortensen) and the other inmates soon realize that they will all be slaughtered unless Forsythe is allowed to repay his long-standing debt. With the lives of Creedmore in the balance, Sharpe and Forsythe are finally brought face-to-rotting-face in a duel that will pit Forsythe's supernatural rage against Sharpe's bloodthirsty instinct for survival.

Comment: Could you provide some plot points that suggest it could be this film?

Comment: Give that the OP has already accepted another film as being the correct answer, you'll need to explain why this is the right one...

Comment: Note that it's perfectly fine to add another matching answer even with an accepted one. It helps other people who might be searching for that movie.

Answer (score -1):

It's called *The Horror Show* (1989).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097527/):

> Detective Lucas McCarthy finally apprehends "Meat Cleaver Max" and watches the electric chair execution from the audience. But killing Max Jenke only elevated him to another level of reality. Now Lucas' family is under attack, his sanity in question, and his house haunted. Aided by a disreputable college professor, can Lucas reclaim his mind, house, and family? Features Lance Henriksen as Lucas McCarthy and Brion James as Max Jenke. One of the few movies featuring these actors as main characters.

Comment: Even though this question already has an accepted answer, you could make your answer better by providing some details why you think this film is the film the OP is looking for. Try to include a poster and a synopsis.